# VCL.Bitmap To FMX.Bitmap

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe4

I found the this code on the web, but FMX.Bitmap does not have a scanline.
Is it possible to copy or draw a VCL.TBitmap to a FMX.Bitmap somehow?

```
{$IFDEF MSWINDOWS}
type
  TBitmap = FMX.Types.TBitmap;
  TVclBitmap = Vcl.Graphics.TBitmap;

procedure TakeScreenshot(Dest: FMX.Types.TBitmap);
var
  DC: HDC;
  Size: TPointF;
  VCLBitmap: TVclBitmap;
  Y: Integer;
begin
  VCLBitmap := nil;
  //Size := FMX.Platform.IFMXScreenService.GetScreenSize;
  DC := GetDC(0);
  try
    VCLBitmap := TVclBitmap.Create;
    VCLBitmap.PixelFormat := pf32bit;
    VCLBitmap.SetSize(Trunc(Size.X), Trunc(Size.Y));
    BitBlt(VCLBitmap.Canvas.Handle, 0, 0, VCLBitmap.Width, VCLBitmap.Height,
      DC, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
    Dest.SetSize(VCLBitmap.Width, VCLBitmap.Height);
    { The format of a FMX bitmap and a 32 bit VCL bitmap is the same, so just
      copy the scanlines. - not true- FMX bitmap does not have ScanLine? }
    for Y := Dest.Height - 1 downto 0 do
      Move(VCLBitmap.ScanLine[Y]^, Dest.ScanLine[Y]^, Dest.Width * 4);
    {Dest.Canvas.DrawBitmap(); Not possible to assign or draw}
  finally
    ReleaseDC(0, DC);
    VCLBitmap.Free;
  end;
end;
{$ENDIF}
```

Comment: As the author of the original code and comment (https://delphi-foundations.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/XE2%20book/13.%20Native%20APIs/Taking%20a%20screenshot/ScreenshotForm.pas), I can say that the FMX TBitmap did originally have a ScanLine property. This however was abstracted out into the Map/Unmap methods in XE3.

Comment: @Chris... yes.. it is your code.  Sorry I did not reference you, but I could not find your website when I was writing this question.  Do you have an example of using Map/Unmap?

Comment: Well I use it in my FMX TClipboard code (http://code.google.com/p/delphi-foundations/source/browse/trunk/FMX%20Utilities/CCR.FMXClipboard.Win.pas - see TWinClipboard.DoAssignBitmap). I'll look at updating the screenshot code later (I'll get a blog post out of it).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use Stream :

```
{$IFDEF MSWINDOWS}

type

  TVclBitmap = Vcl.Graphics.TBitmap;

procedure TakeScreenshot(Dest: TBitmap);
var
  DC: HDC;
  Size: TPointF;
  VCLBitmap: TVclBitmap;
  Y: Integer;
  MS: TMemoryStream;
begin
  MS := TMemoryStream.Create;
  VCLBitmap := nil;
  // Size := FMX.Platform.IFMXScreenService.GetScreenSize;
  DC := GetDC(0);
  Size.X := 500;
  Size.Y := 500;
  try
    VCLBitmap := TVclBitmap.Create;
    VCLBitmap.PixelFormat := pf32bit;
    VCLBitmap.SetSize(Trunc(Size.X), Trunc(Size.Y));
    BitBlt(VCLBitmap.Canvas.Handle, 0, 0, VCLBitmap.Width, VCLBitmap.Height, DC,
      0, 0, SRCCOPY);
    Dest.SetSize(VCLBitmap.Width, VCLBitmap.Height);
    { The format of a FMX bitmap and a 32 bit VCL bitmap is the same, so just
      copy the scanlines. - not true- FMX bitmap does not have ScanLine? }
    VCLBitmap.SaveToStream(MS);
    MS.Position := 0;
    Dest.LoadFromStream(MS);
    MS.Free;
    { Dest.Canvas.DrawBitmap(); Not possible to assign or draw }
  finally
    ReleaseDC(0, DC);
    VCLBitmap.Free;
  end;
end;
{$ENDIF}
```

Comment: You should protect MS so that you don't leak it

Comment: This is very slow. (Very!) A faster version would be to use Map to access the pixel data of the FMX bitmap, and Scanline to access the pixel data of the VCL bitmap, and copy / convert pixels directly.

Answer (score 1):

```
unit uScreenShot;

interface

uses
  FMX.Graphics;

type
  IScreenShot = interface
    ['{026A7002-AD30-47FD-A7B8-D633F3FAB130}']
    function Execute: IScreenShot;
    function Bitmap: TBitmap;
  end;

implementation

end.

unit uScreenShot.Clss;

{ =====================================================================
   How to use:
     TScreenShot.New(YourBitmapObject).Execute;
     TScreenShot.New.Execute.Bitmap;
  ====================================================================== }

interface

uses
  Vcl.Graphics,
  FMX.Graphics,
  uScreenShot;

type
  TVclBitmap = Vcl.Graphics.TBitmap;

  TScreenShot = class(TInterfacedObject, IScreenShot)
  private
    FBitmap: TBitmap;
    FTarget: TBitmap;
    class procedure TakeScreenshot(const ATarget: TBitmap); static;
    class procedure CopyBitmap(const ASource: TVclBitmap; const ATarget: TBitmap); static;
  protected
    function Execute: IScreenShot;
    function Bitmap: TBitmap;
  public
    class function New: IScreenShot; overload; static;
    class function New(const ATarget: TBitmap): IScreenShot; overload; static;
    constructor Create; overload;
    constructor Create(const ATarget: TBitmap); overload;
    destructor Destroy; override;
  end;

implementation

uses
  FMX.Forms,
  Winapi.Windows,
  System.SysUtils,
  System.Classes,
  System.Types;

{ TScreenShot }

class function TScreenShot.New: IScreenShot;
begin
  Result := TScreenShot.Create;
end;

class function TScreenShot.New(const ATarget: FMX.Graphics.TBitmap): IScreenShot;
begin
  Result := TScreenShot.Create(ATarget);
end;

constructor TScreenShot.Create;
begin
  inherited;
  FTarget := nil;
  FBitmap := FMX.Graphics.TBitmap.Create;
end;

constructor TScreenShot.Create(const ATarget: FMX.Graphics.TBitmap);
begin
  Self.Create;
  FTarget := ATarget;
end;

destructor TScreenShot.Destroy;
begin
  FTarget := nil;
  FreeAndNil(FBitmap);
  inherited;
end;

function TScreenShot.Bitmap: FMX.Graphics.TBitmap;
begin
  Result := FBitmap;
end;

function TScreenShot.Execute: IScreenShot;
begin
  Result := Self;
  TScreenShot.TakeScreenshot(FBitmap);
  if Assigned(FTarget) then
  begin
    FTarget.Size := FBitmap.Size;
    FTarget.CopyFromBitmap(FBitmap);
  end;
end;

class procedure TScreenShot.TakeScreenshot(const ATarget: FMX.Graphics.TBitmap);
var
  LDc: HDC;
  LSize: TPoint;
  LVclBitmap: TVclBitmap;
begin
  LSize.X := Screen.Size.Width;
  LSize.Y := Screen.Size.Height;
  // Getting Screenshot
  LDc := GetDC(0);
  LVclBitmap := TVclBitmap.Create;
  try
    LVclBitmap.PixelFormat := pf32bit;
    LVclBitmap.SetSize(LSize.X, LSize.Y);
    BitBlt(LVclBitmap.Canvas.Handle, 0, 0, LVclBitmap.Width, LVclBitmap.Height, LDc, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
    ATarget.SetSize(LVclBitmap.Width, LVclBitmap.Height);
    // Saving Screenshot
    TScreenShot.CopyBitmap(LVclBitmap, ATarget);
  finally
    ReleaseDC(0, LDc);
    LVclBitmap.Free;
  end;
end;

class procedure TScreenShot.CopyBitmap(const ASource: TVclBitmap; const ATarget: FMX.Graphics.TBitmap);
var
  LStream: TMemoryStream;
begin
  LStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    ASource.SaveToStream(LStream);
    LStream.Position := 0;
    ATarget.LoadFromStream(LStream);
  finally
    LStream.Free;
  end;
end;

end.
```

Comment: While your answer may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. You can edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/28447183)